# append / appendChild not working on all items

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to move all the list items from an list to another using only javascript but for some reason only half of them are actually moved.

Heres a working example of what I'm doing:

```js
var results_ul = document.getElementById('results');
var stores_li = document.getElementsByClassName('store-list-item');

for (var x = 0; x < stores_li.length; x++) {
  document.getElementById('hide').appendChild(stores_li[x]);
  stores_li[x].className += ' teste';
}
```

```html
<p>results</p>
<ul id="results">
  <li class="store-list-item">Teste 1</li>
  <li class="store-list-item">Teste 2</li>
  <li class="store-list-item">Teste 3</li>
  <li class="store-list-item">Teste 4</li>
</ul>
<p>Hide:</p>
<ul id="hide"></ul>
```

What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a *live* list.

When you append the element to a different element, you change its position in the list.

So it starts off as:

```
1 2 3 4
```

Then you move the first one:

```
2 3 4 1
```

Then you access the second one … but the second one is now `3` because everything has shuffled down the list.

---

You could copy each element into an array (which will not be a *live* list) and then iterate over that array to move them (so they won't change positions as you go).

Alternatively, you could use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/checklist) which returns a **non-live** list.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. Now I understand perfectly what the issue was :)
 querySelectorAll  did do the trick!

Answer (score 2):

You should better use `querySelectorAll` than `getElementsByClassName`

```js
var results_ul = document.getElementById('results');
var stores_li = document.querySelectorAll('.store-list-item');

stores_li.forEach((item)=>{
  document.getElementById('hide').appendChild(item);
  item.className += ' teste';
});
```

```html
<p>results</p>
<ul id="results">
  <li class="store-list-item">Teste 1</li>
  <li class="store-list-item">Teste 2</li>
  <li class="store-list-item">Teste 3</li>
  <li class="store-list-item">Teste 4</li>
</ul>
<p>Hide:</p>
<ul id="hide"></ul>
```

Comment: This reads more like a game of spot-the-difference than an answer. What did you change? Why should it solve the problem.

Comment: it does solve the problem, though, but i agree not a proper answer

Comment: @Quentin I'm not good at English. When I answered to Question, I spend a lot of time. I just can serve solution. I don't have ability of teach with English yet. I just want to help someone.

Comment: I think my answer can solve the problem. any problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try use *querySelectorAll* . It'll returns a non-live list. That's what you need.

```
var stores_li = document.querySelectorAll('.store-list-item');
```

To increase more information:

**Live** : when the changes in the DOM are reflected in the collection. The content suffers the change when a node is modified.

**Non-Live** : when any change in the DOM does not affect the content of the collection.

*document.getElementsByClassName() is an HTMLCollection, and is live.*

*document.querySelectorAll() is a NodeList and is not live.*

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are removing each element from the first list and inserting into the new list. After you remove 2 elements it will have only 2 elements in the first list but now you are searching the 3 rd index in the loop which is not there. So to make it work i have prepended each element from the last.

```js
var results_ul = document.getElementById('results');
var stores_li = document.getElementsByClassName('store-list-item');
var hide_ul = document.getElementById('hide');
for (var x = 0, y = stores_li.length; x < y; x++) {
  hide_ul.insertBefore(stores_li[y-x-1],hide_ul.firstChild);
  stores_li[x].className += ' teste';
}
```

```html
<p>results</p>
<ul id="results">
  <li class="store-list-item">Teste 1</li>
  <li class="store-list-item">Teste 2</li>
  <li class="store-list-item">Teste 3</li>
  <li class="store-list-item">Teste 4</li>
</ul>
<p>Hide:</p>
<ul id="hide"></ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Or you may want to clone the element with Jquery and you can push into the clonned ones then delete the orginals from top. I could not find any equivalent of clone() for js but if you want to check link is [**here**](http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=de13fd25073c3f2456580040acb037c2)

Answer (score -4):

```
var results_ul = document.getElementById('results');
var stores_li = document.getElementsByClassName('store-list-item');

while(stores_li.length>0) {
   document.getElementById('hide').appendChild(stores_li[0]);
   stores_li[x].className += ' teste';
}
```

Comment: This reads more like a game of spot-the-difference than an answer. What did you change? Why should it solve the problem?

Comment: `while(stores_li.length>0)` this condition will never not be true. You've created an infinite loop.